# How can return response without queryset in Django REST Framwork views

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using django rest framework for serialize the data, I came across a scenario where i have to return two different queryset result in on view, so i tried in this way but failed to get response

```
q1 = tbl_nt.objects.values_list('id', 'value', 'geometry')

q2 = tbl_network.objects.values_list('id', 'value', 'geometry')
```

Tried following methods for build queryset

```
queryset = (q1) | (q2)

queryset = list(q1) + list(q2)

queryset = chain(q1, q2)

queryset = list(chain(q1, q2))
```

One solution that comes in my mind get the union of both queryset, serialize them and send in response so i write down this code for view just testing

```
class SnippetList(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        snippets = tbl_network.objects.all()
        json = serializers.serialize('json', snippets)
        return Response(json)
```

Now this exception is facing

'Cannot apply DjangoModelPermissions on a view that does not have `.model` or `.queryset` property.'

My strategy is simple i want to create list, serialize the list and send in response

So my question is how to pass response without queryset?
I this approach is correct?

I have also posted question related to this problem where one solution is posted implement inheritance but i don't want to change Database table structure

[django combine queries on two different base models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457996/django-combine-queries-on-two-different-base-models/)

Comment: Have you seen this referring to your error message? https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/issues/8

Comment: @Bozdos According do this post i have to change permissions but i am using both model and non-model views. So i think it will not work for model queryset